# ngAnimate: Tooltip using ngShow is fading out, but not fading in

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

According to the Angular [ngAnimate docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), using class based animation with ngShow is just a matter of using CSS transition with the `.foo.ng-hide` class.  When I do this to show and hide a tooltip, however, the tip appears without the transition.  Dismissing the tip, though, shows the fade-out.  What am I missing?  [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/scottmcd/pen/wMboBz).

When I inspect the code, I see that the ng-animate classes are applied for the fade-out, but not for the fade-in.  That is, when angular removes the `.ng-hide` class, it just removes it without the `.ng-hide-animate` and `ng-hide-remove` classes, which I'd expected to see.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="tooltipping" ng-controller="tipCtrl as tip">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="tip.toggle()">Toggle the Tip</a> 
      <span class="tip" ng-show="tip.showTip">Tip: Usually 15-20% of the bill.</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  display: block;
  position: relative; 
}
.tip {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tip.ng-hide {
  transition: 5s ease all;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
  angular.module('tooltipping', ['ngAnimate']);
  angular.module('tooltipping').controller('tipCtrl', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.showTip = false;

    vm.toggle = function(){
      vm.showTip = !vm.showTip;
    };
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/scottmcd/pen/QyRZjp).

I've added a second tooltip that works properly, with a class name of .working-tip

The critical difference is where the transition property is in the CSS.  Compare:

```
.tip {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tip.ng-hide {
  transition: 3s ease all;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

and

```
.working-tip {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;  
  left: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 3s ease all;
}
.working-tip.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The only difference is that the transition property is in the block for the class rather than the class + ng-hide.  Doing it the second way results in the expected behavior.  I'm still not quite sure why, so I'd love to hear any explanation.